# Java Lambda Expressions: Why should it be required to refer to the method name?

Tags: java, lambda

say I have a functional interface and Lambda and the standard use:

```
interface NumericMethod{
   int operation(int number);
}
NumericMethod add1 = (x) -> x+1
System.out.println(add1.operation(7))//but not (...add1(7))
```

So my question is, why not simply add1(7)? There is only one method that can be called.

Comment: What? That's not even valid Java syntax.

Comment: Please provide a working [mcve]

Comment: Do you mean `NumericMethod add1 = (x) -> x + 1;`?

Comment: Because there is no function in Java. Only methods. And add1 is thus not a function, but an object of type NumericMethod. The designers could have authorized this syntax, but it would make things even harder, introduce naming conflicts, etc. without any substantial gain.

Comment: You can have functional interfaces with `default` methods. What do you do then?

Comment: @JBNizet: Can you explain the naming conflict? To me the gain is not having to specify a method where it is unambiguously implied. As far as there being no function in Java, I thought that was the point of Lambda expressions.

Comment: Well, if you have a method named add1() in a class, and you also define a local variable add1 of type NumericMethod, and you call add1(), what is being called? The method, or the NumericMethod? The point of lambda is not to more easily call methods. The point is to more easily create instances of functional interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code `add1` isn't a method, it's an object. If, when defining lambdas, the Java 8 teams decided that classes with one method can be called directly, it would have left a whole lot of mess to clean up regarding the ever narrowing line between objects and methods.

Comment: Are there not languages where this sort of syntax is allowed? To me, a class with a single method would be pretty much that method and so an object of that class would be the method and thus functions could be objects in Java.

Comment: @Jeff just because something is possible doesn't mean that it should be done, or that it's a good idea. The Java language designers simply decided that it wasn't worth it.

Comment: @JBNizet: Understood; all I can say is that it seemed more natural to me to refer to the method in this way.